# ValueError in Seaborn: Cannot interpret input value

Tags: python, csv, seaborn

Hoping to get a second opinion on my code to figure out why this graph isn't generating. I think the reason I'm getting an error is the csv columns aren't formatted correctly. Take a look

**Python Code:**

```
import csv
from csv import reader
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

with open('MF.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    line_count = 0
    fields = ["Runtime", "Date"]
    with open('runtime.csv', 'w+') as runtime:
        writer = csv.writer(runtime)
        for row in reader:
            writer.writerow([row[2], row[3], row[6]])

thedata = pd.read_csv('runtime.csv')

sns.lineplot(x="Date", y="Average", data=thedata)
```

**Runtime.csv**

```
Duration    Date    Average
113 1/25/2019   5.9
92  2/1/2019    7.1
96  2/8/2019    9.1
95  2/15/2019   4.5
106 2/22/2019   5.5
97  3/1/2019    5.8
110 3/8/2019    4.1
142 3/15/2019   8.5
77  3/22/2019   9.0
96  3/29/2019   5.7
113 4/5/2019    6.1
101 4/12/2019   9.0
101 4/19/2019   5.7
181 4/26/2019   7.0
130 5/3/2019    7.1
106 5/10/2019   9.4
114 5/17/2019   8.2
103 5/31/2019   7.1
136 6/8/2019    6.4
102 6/21/2019   7.5
```

**There are more rows, but I just grabbed a slice from the CSV file^^

**Error**:

```
ValueError: Could not interpret input 'Date'
```

Comment: Have you looked at the data that you are attempting to plot? `print(thedata)` This suggests that `Date` is not a column in your input. Also, if you've just copied the first few lines of `runtime.csv`, unmodified, then you probably need to specify `sep="\t"` param when loading using pandas.

Comment: Try editing `MF.csv` to only contain a few row and delete `runtime.csv`, do you still get the error?

Comment: @Alex does Unnamed: 0, Unnamed: 1, etc. Suggest an unnamed column? I see now, Duration, Date, and Average are located in Row 0 as opposed to being columns. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @nick_rinaldi that suggests that your header row isn't the first row in the file. You can set `header=1` in the `pd.read_csv` call to tell pandas what line (counting from zero) the header is on.